# Moving react into seperate component files without Node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not using Node, how do move my react code (jsx) which is currently in a text/babel script tag into separate component files? I have tried moving them and then referencing them in the html file but as soon as it hits the first bit of HTML it throws a syntax error, I have tried both .jsx and .js extensions of the file and when I include it I give it the script type of text/babel.

```
<script src="components/nav.jsx" type="text/babel" ></script>
<script src="components/map.jsx" type="text/babel" ></script>
<script src="components/app.jsx" type="text/babel" ></script>
```

Comment: Could you please paste the error message ?? BTW I'm recommend to use webpack instead of using `text/babel` script tag

Comment: @TIJ If I put it all in a singular file it works fine. However if I split it and then reference them I get 'Navbar is not defined'. I will update the post with how I reference the files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are transforming your JSX in the browser, you would have to attach each component to the window object.

As an example:

```
var Nav = React.createClass({ ... });
window.Nav = Nav;
```

Or more tersely:

```
window.Nav = React.createClass({ ... });
```

Comment: This technically *works* however is considered bad pracitce. See [Dmitriy's answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37764638/1339693)

Answer (score 0):

[Jim Nielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1339693/jim-nielsen) is right, however it is considered to be a bad practice to expose parts of you code to a global scope and to transpile JSX in the browser. Instead you should consider to use some building system like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/).

This way you would be able to use [es2015 import syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import) to import components from one file to another, bundle everything in one file and much more additional benefits like code minification, sourcemaps, livereload etc.

[Setting up React for ES6 with Webpack and Babel](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html)

[Using React with Webpack Tutorial](https://blog.risingstack.com/using-react-with-webpack-tutorial/)

[Related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763006/splitting-up-react-components-into-multiple-files/37763408#37763408)