# Splitting up React components into multiple files

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have only been learning React in a week so I am new to it and I am trying to write a simple todo app.

Originally I wrote all of the components in one file and loaded that file into the HTML file and it worked great. Now I am refactoring and trying to split the components into different files.

My full code is on my Github https://github.com/yasgreen93/todolist-react on the `extracting-files` branch.

I have split up each component into different files and have an linked them in script tags into my HTML. This is what my HTML file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Todo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.16/browser.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/components/TodoListApp.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/components/CompleteTodo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/components/TodoList.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/components/SingleTodo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/components/AddTodo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/components/CompleteTodoButton.js"></script>

    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <TodoListApp url="/api/todos" updateUrl="/api/todos/update" pollInterval={2000}/>,
        document.getElementById('container')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the console, I always get the error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: TodoListApp is not defined`. I have tried loading them in different orders with no success. I have also watched many videos where they do very similar approaches without using webpack and it works for them. I would like to get this working first without using webpack and then move on to learning that.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add your components to a global `window` variable in order to use them in html `script` tag. Like `window.TodoListApp =...`. `var` declaration is relative to a file in which you declare it.

But it is considered to be a bad practice to expose parts of you code to a global scope and to transpile JSX in the browser. Instead you should consider to use some building system like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/).

This way you would be able to use [es2015 import syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import) to import components from one file to another, bundle everything in one file and much more additional benefits like code minification, sourcemaps, livereload etc.

[Setting up React for ES6 with Webpack and Babel](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html)

[Using React with Webpack Tutorial](https://blog.risingstack.com/using-react-with-webpack-tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I am not using ES6 which the resources you have provided are all using. Would it still work for ES5?

Comment: Yes. Just don't use babel loader and use regular node CommonJS modules - https://webpack.github.io/docs/commonjs.html

Comment: I agree with the author. For a less steep learing curve it must be possible to do this without webpack.